# Conversion error in the component use Converter of JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters

I have a problem to catch objects selected in the combo using a ConvertGeneric, which is released an exception can not convert. Does anyone have a say.

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.ELException: /app/administrador/CadastrarUsuario.xhtml @145,79 value="#{usuarioController.user.roles}": Cannot convert com.app.entity.Perfil@20 of type class amc.scda.entity.Perfil to interface java.util.List

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="cbxPerfil" required="true"
   requiredMessage="#{rotulos.perfil_mandatory}"
   value="#{userController.user.roles}" converter="genericConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{userController.listPerfilSelect}" />
    <f:ajax render="cbxPerfil" event="valueChange"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

```
public interface SampleEntity {

    public Integer getId();

}
```

```
@FacesConverter(value = "genericConverter", forClass = SampleEntity.class)
public class GenericConverter implements Converter, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6461922703911161947L;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            return this.getAttributesFrom(component).get(value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component, Object value) {

        if (value != null && !"".equals(value)) {

            SampleEntity entity = (SampleEntity) value;

            // adiciona item como atributo do componente
            this.addAttribute(component, entity);

            Integer codigo = entity.getId();
            if (codigo != null) {
                return String.valueOf(codigo);
            }
        }

        return (String) value;
    }

    protected void addAttribute(UIComponent component, SampleEntity o) {
        String key = o.getId().toString();
        this.getAttributesFrom(component).put(key, o);
    }

    protected Map<String, Object> getAttributesFrom(UIComponent component) {
        return component.getAttributes();
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Perfil implements GrantedAuthority, SampleEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3968396919486158590L;

    private Integer id;
    private String description;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "role_id_seq", sequenceName = "role_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "role_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "role_description", unique = true)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public String getAuthority() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Perfil other = (Perfil) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: selectOneMenu expects list of SelectItem not Perfil objects. You can create method with signature `List <SelectItem> getPerfilList` and use it in select one menu.

Comment: @VasilLukach: that's only for JSF 1.x. OP is using JSF 2.x which is already 6 years available.

Comment: Roberto, error message says `#{userController.user.roles}` is a `List`, not a `Perfil`. Seems pretty clear.

Comment: rules is my list of profiles in the use JSF 2 project with spring security